# ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' for modifying when installing RStan in Rstudio in Windows 7

Tags: c++, r, stan

I am trying to install RStan according to https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started

I used windows 7, RStudio 0.98.501 and R x64 3.0.2

I installed packages inline and Rcpp successfully.

The result of C++ test as follows:

```
> src <- ' 
+   std::vector<std::string> s; 
+   s.push_back("hello");
+   s.push_back("world");
+   return Rcpp::wrap(s);
+ '
> hellofun <- cxxfunction(body = src, includes = '', plugin = 'Rcpp', verbose = FALSE)
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
> cat(hellofun(), '\n')
hello world
```

I thought thhe "hello world" means I installed C++ correctly.

Then I input the following codes:

```
> Sys.setenv(R_MAKEVARS_USER = "foobar")
> options(repos = c(getOption("repos"), rstan = "http://wiki.rstan-repo.googlecode.com/git/"))
> install.packages('rstan', type = 'source')
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://wiki.rstan-repo.googlecode.com/git/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
trying URL 'http://wiki.rstan-repo.googlecode.com/git/src/contrib/rstan_2.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4515994 bytes (4.3 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 4.3 Mb

ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/00LOCK-rstan'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library" C:\Users    \BYNBUT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4WmSTV/downloaded_packages/rstan_2.2.0.tar.gz' had status 3
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rstan’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\byny\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4WmSTV\downloaded_packages’
```

Then,

```
> library(rstan)
Error in library(rstan) : there is no package called ‘rstan’
```

RStan installed unsuccessfully.

I have no idea how to solve the issue.

**Updates:** I uninstalled the all the versions of R and installed the latest version 64 bits R. Then I installed RStan again. The problem solved.

Comment: This is not really an RStan issue but more of a general issue of installing R packages. First, if you have an aborted installation, you should do as it suggests and "Try removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/00LOCK-rstan'". Second, there may have been a temporary network interruption that prevented the download from googlecode or those 404 Not Found messages may just be indicating that there is no rstan_2.0.0.tar.gz in the other repositories.

Comment: Thank you. I installed a new version of R, then the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Everything worked fine until the "hello world" of the C++ installation check. Then, I ran the suggested lines:

options(repos = c(getOption("repos"), rstan = "http://wiki.rstan-repo.googlecode.com/git/"))
install.packages('rstan', type = 'source')

I had plenty of 404 errors. The last lines of the output were:

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\U111499\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYfj24v\downloaded_packages’

Then I went to the package tab of RStudio, clicked "Install Packages", selected "Install from: Package Archive File", then the "rstan_2.2.0.tar.gz" that I found under the path mentionned above. That finally seemed to do the trick. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
install.packages("rstan", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org", dependencies = TRUE)
```

See here: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/304